# Android app structure - Activity vs Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

In the last year I have taken over two existing projects, each of which was structured very differently.

Project A had one Activity, and then each area of functionality was contained as a Fragment within that activity. The areas of functionality were not related - there were the usual type of screens such as account, settings, help, etc. Overall there were probably around 25 fragments. The fragment management code was rather complex and tricky to debug.

Project B had one Activity per each Fragment. It was a complex project with many areas of functionality and the manifest listed almost 30 activities.

I was wondering which was the 'correct' solution? What are the pros and cons of each? If I were starting a new project from scratch which model should I follow?

Comment: Project A seems more logical to me. And you can have a unique ActionBar (or a custom toolbar of your complete invention). I'd say even more efficient, since you don't have a lot of containers, when only one is sufficient. I also guess all these activities in Project B are preallocated in memory, since you have to declare them in the Manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no "correct" solution. Whichever architecture makes the most sense to you is probably the one that you should choose for your projects.

Think of Activities as a collection of zero or more Fragments, and Fragments as a way to separate pieces of an Activity into smaller logical or functional pieces. From there, decide how you personally want to organize these pieces and go with it.

Dianne Hackborn and Adam Powell addressed this question at the [2014 Google I/O Android Fireside Chat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3meJyiYWFw#t=880) as well, and I think they did a good job of explaining how the two are just different levels of abstraction for the same concepts.